# ASP.NET - issues with connecting html, javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web-applications, web

I've got this code and what it does is simply display a pop-up that consists of 2 images, a background and a clickable image(button). The idea is that when the user clicks on the button, it displays their user id. The setup is just javascript & HTML within in an ASPX file (so that it can actually read the user's id etc). When i do a 'response.write' in the .NET section, it displays the user's ID on the screen no problem. However, my problem is that the javascript can't see 'userid', so when i do an 'alert(userid) in javascript, it doesn't actually display the ID, its just blank.

Heres my code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="dbfunctions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="generalfunctions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="system.data" %>
<script language="VB" runat="server">

    Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Public userid As Integer
        Dim rst As DataView
        Dim connstr As String = getStrConn(HttpContext.Current)
        userid = Session("u_id")
        connstr = getStrConn(HttpContext.Current)
        'response.write(userid)
    End Sub
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function loadPage(){
        var userid=<%=userid%>;
        alert(userid)
    }

</script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Please update your details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="userid" value="@userid" />
    <img id="img" src="corkboard.png" />
    <a id="b1" href="#" onclick="loadPage()">
        <img src="button.png" style="border-style: none" />
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I think i'm almost there, the aspx & javascript individually work, its just a matter of bringing them together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can tell your preprocessor to stick vars from code behind into the aspx page when the page is being rendered. the vars must be public, and placed in your page partial class:

```
<script language="VB" runat="server">
    Public userid As Integer
    Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        userid = 32
    End Sub
</script>
```

and then use a preprocessor directive to stick it into the aspx page:

```
var userid=<%=userid%>;  //this line will be rendered as "var userid=32"
function loadPage(){    
    alert(userid)
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I have ammended my code to include what you've said and it still isn't working, is there anything else i can try? I've edited my question to show the new code.

Comment: @SamFarr you have declared the `userid` inside your `page_load` which makes it a local variable of the page load method. you need to move it outside of the `page_load`

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any resources you would recommend to improve my knowledge on ASP.NET?

Comment: @SamFarr well im sure there are plenty of tutorials on the web, but id suggest you to improve your knowledge by trial and error. try doing something until you succeed, and then move to the next 'project'. this is the best way to learn IMO, and if you get stuck you can either search on google or post here.

Answer (score 0):

this is not going to work this way. Reason: ASP is executed on server-side, Javascript on client side. This means your "userid" variable does no longer exist once Javascrpt is being executed. You could "store" it somewhere where it will survive HTML rendering, e.g. as value in a hidden input element:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="userid" value="@userid" />
```

And then in your Javascript code you read the value of that element:

```js
function loadPage(){    
  var userid=document.getElementById("userid");
alert(userid);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your feedback, it still isn't working though :(. I've added <input type="hidden" id="userid" value="@userid" /> to the body of the HTML and var userid=document.getElementById("userid");  to the function but it still just says "object" when i perform the alert....

Comment: Argh! Forgot .Value...

var userid=document.getElementById("userid").Value;

Comment: Thanks for having a go :).